# Аннотация Hibernate @ManyToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate, аннотации, many-to-many

Есть такой пример:

```
@Entity
public class Student
{
    @Id
    private long id;

        private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable (name="student_university",
       joinColumns=@JoinColumn (name="student_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="university_id"))
    private List<University> universities;

    // set/get не представлены
}

@Entity
public class University
{
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="student_university",
       joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="university_id"), 
       inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
    private List<Student> students;

    // set/get не представлены
}
```

Вот описание к этому примеру - Параметр joinColumns указывает на поле, которое используется для прямой связи (идентификатор student_id). Параметр inverseJoinColumns указывает на поле, которое используется для обратной связи (идентификатор university_id). Для указания столбцов связи из таблицы используется аннотация @JoinColumn.

Мне непонятно отсюда, что значит "для прямой связи" и "для обратной связи".Почему параметры подставляются в joinColumns и inverseJoinColumns в таком, как бы обратном порядке?

Comment: Полное описание необходимо с одной стороны. На второй стороне достаточно добавить mapped by, и указать поле первого класса entity.

Comment: Указав, поле первого класса, что я этим говорю? подтянуть эту сущность(в котором находится указанное поле) , в поле над которым я написал mappedBy?

Comment: Вы не правильно определяете связь Many-To-Many. Поле `students` должно быть аннотировано: `@ManyToMany(mappedBy="universities")`.

Comment: это не я написал. Пример отсюда - http://java-online.ru/hibernate-entities.xhtml